# Быстрая обработка сетевых пакетов

Tags: java, сокет

Как лучше реализовать класс Packet? Вот например приходят мне данные из socket.getInputStream() и я загружаю это в "Packet p = new Packet(inStream)", потом я буду читать его p.ReadInt() и т.д. Внутри пакета подгружать все в BufferedInputStream, а потом считывать? Размер пакета около 500 кбайт будет в среднем, тогда может лучше использовать обычный InputStream? Интересуют производительные решения c аргументацией.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html

Answer (score 1):

InputStream и Packet - лишние обертки. Используйте [SocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html), можно в синхронном, можно в асинхронном виде. Читайте в [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), у него есть getInt() и всё прочее.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте NIO. Например, SocketChannel.